# Programming a chess game in Java, and gameOver boolean not working

Tags: java, chess

I'm trying to make a chess game in Java that can be played on the console. For each move, the game asks the player for a piece, (for example 12 for the piece in the second row, third column) and a final location (for example 32 for the fourth row, third column). Everything is working perfectly, including tests to see if the move is illegal and if a given player is in check, but my gameOver boolean seems to be changing the value of my board array before the first move is asked for.

Here is the relevant code. From my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] board = {   {12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 14, 13, 12},
                        {11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11},
                        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                        {0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
                        {21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21},
                        {22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 24, 23, 22}
                    };
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean oneTurn = true;
    while(!(gameOver(oneTurn, board))) {
        printBoard(board);
        System.out.println(((oneTurn) ? "1's" : "2's") +  " turn");
        System.out.print("What piece? ");
        int origin = scan.nextInt();
```

The gameOver boolean, which tests to see if there are any moves the current player can make that are legal and won't put the player in check:

```
public static boolean gameOver(boolean oneTurn, int[][] board) {
    for (int a = 0; a<8; a++) {
        for(int b = 0; b<8; b++) {
            for (int c = 0; c<8; c++) {
                for(int d = 0; d<8; d++) {
                    if(board[a][b] / 10 == (oneTurn ? 1 : 2) && !(illegal(oneTurn, 10*a+b, 10*c+d, board)) && !(illegalCheck(oneTurn, 10*a+b, 10*c+d, board))) return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The check method, which tries to find a legal move the other player can do that will eliminate the king:

```
public static boolean check(boolean oneTurn, int[][] board) {
    int king = kingNum(oneTurn, board);
    for (int a = 0; a<8; a++) {
        for(int b = 0; b<8; b++) {
            if(board[a][b] / 10 == (oneTurn ? 2 : 1) && !(illegal(!oneTurn, 10*a+b, king, board))) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The illegalCheck method, which tests to see if a move will put the player in check. I think this is where the problem lies. I tried to make a separate newBoard so that the original board wouldn't change, but it still creates the problem.

```
public static boolean illegalCheck(boolean oneTurn, int origin, int dest, int[][] board) {
    int[][] newBoard = board;
    newBoard[dest / 10][dest % 10] = board[origin / 10][origin % 10];
    newBoard[origin / 10][origin % 10] = 0;
    if(check(oneTurn, newBoard)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

When I run the program for the first time, the first output I get is this:

```
    |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 |  4 |  5 |  6 |  7 |
_____________________________________________

0   | 1R |    | 1B | 1Q | 1K | 1B | 1N | 1R |
_____________________________________________

1   | 1P | 1P | 1P | 1P | 1P | 1P | 1P | 1P |
_____________________________________________

2   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
_____________________________________________

3   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
_____________________________________________

4   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
_____________________________________________

5   |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |    |
_____________________________________________

6   | 2P | 2P | 2P | 2P | 2P | 2P | 2P | 2P |
_____________________________________________

7   | 2R | 2N | 2B | 2Q | 2K | 2B | 2N | 2R |
_____________________________________________

1's turn
What piece?
```

The first legal move found by gameOver is the knight moving, so I think that's why the knight isn't showing up on the first board. When I put the printBoard method before the boolean test, the board prints perfectly.

I just began learning to program recently, so I would appreciate any advice about why this would be happening. It could be something blatantly obvious that I'm missing. Let me know if there are other details I can provide. Thank you!

Comment: your gameOver function is not readable at all. how hard is it to choose some meaningful variable names and not to try to go too fancy?!!!

Comment: It's not bad. Just unnecessary. Also, why is it not readable? And why is it "too fancy"? Feel free to edit it without the fluff.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. I thought this was going to be a quick learning project for myself whose code only I would read, but this little problem has made me frustrated enough to resort to outside sources. The letters in gameOver are just indices for the array (row a, column b to row c, column d). illegalCheck is probably a bad variable name, but it tests to see if a move from ab to cd will put the player in check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
int[][] newBoard = board;
newBoard[dest / 10][dest % 10] = board[origin / 10][origin % 10];
newBoard[origin / 10][origin % 10] = 0;
```

you're creating `newBoard` as a new reference *to the same array object* as `board`, and then proceeding to modify the array.  You can copy it instead like this:

```
int[][] newBoard = new int[8][];
for (int i = 0; i < newBoard.length; ++i)
    newBoard[i] = board[i].clone();
```

Java's multidimensional arrays are arrays of references to other arrays (because arrays are objects), so first we create a new top-level array, then assign copies of the subsidiary arrays into it.  (There are a bunch of rules about `Object.clone()` and `Cloneable`, but all you have to know here is that cloning an array makes a new array with the same values.  For multidimensional arrays this is a shallow copy (the copy refers to the same subsidiary arrays), so we can't just call `board.clone()` and be done with it.)

Comment: Thank you, I think that solution worked! So for future reference, it's clear that the same second-level arrays were being accessed by each top-level array throughout the program. But were the top-level arrays also the same throughout, or could I have two arrays named board that were references to different things?

Comment: You can have two references named `board` that point to different arrays, yes.  (If a class has a field named `board`, each instance of that class could reference a different array from that field, for example.  Similarly with locals in different or recursive methods.)  The arrays themselves have no knowledge of what references point to them.  But just assigning `board = ...` doesn't create a new array unless the `...` contains `new` or calls a library function documented to return a new array.

Answer (score 1):

If you believe it is due to the copy of the array, try `System.arraycopy` in illegalCheck.

Comment: I changed my initialization to this:

  int[][] newBoard = new int[8][8];
  System.arraycopy(board, 0, newBoard, 0, board.length);

But it didn't work. Is this the correct use of arraycopy? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a debugger and setting some breakpoints so you can see what exactly is going on, that way you won't be guessing.

More info on debugging sessions with java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I have absolutely no experience with debuggers, but I'll give it a try. Do you know how a boolean could possibly be changing a variable in a different method? My understanding was that variables can only be changed inside their own methods, but that seems to be incorrect in this case.

Comment: I haven't really looked at the whole code, if you need help you can create a test case that reproduces the same behavior, if it does, edit your question and post only the test case. Also, I didn't see a gameOver boolean variable, I see a method with that identifier instead. Do a test case or use a debugger, that should be your best bet.